# Page rendered but after commandButton clicked property not found

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I have a settings page on which different settings are displayed. Settings can be freely edited and then saved. Here's code fragment with such (single) setting:

```
<h:form>
    <p:panel id="panel" header="header">
        <p:messages id="messages" />
            <p:inputMask value="#{settingsBean.getSettingByCode('SSTMOUT').value}" mask="9?99"/>
    </p:panel>
    <p:commandButton value="Save" update="panel" actionListener="#{settingsBean.saveAllSettings}"/>
</h:form>
```

For above code, there's backing bean SettingsBean with getSettingByCode method as follows:

```
public Setting getSettingByCode(String code) {
   for(Setting sett : settings) {
       if (sett.getCode().equals(code)) {
           return sett;
       }
   }
   // Lacking Settings are created during application startup by different class, so this code should never be called
   return null;
}
```

Now what is strange. If I go to this page, it renders fine - settings are displayed (for testing purposes I left only one setting to be edited), I can type everything in inputMask field. Also, all properties of beans are accessed without any problems at first page access. But when I click "Save" button, exception is thrown with this stack:

```
WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) /pages/secure/a.xhtml @17,161 value="#{settingsBean.getSettingByCode('SSTMOUT').value}": The class 'packageName.app.beans.SettingsBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy' does not have the property 'getSettingByCode'.: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/secure/a.xhtml @17,161 value="#{settingsBean.getSettingByCode('SSTMOUT').value}": The class 'packageName.app.beans.SettingsBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy' does not have the property 'getSettingByCode'.
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getConverter(ComponentUtils.java:126) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputRenderer.java:171) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel.processValidators(Panel.java:287) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.primefaces.component.layout.Layout.processValidators(Layout.java:233) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```

After this exception, nothing happens and no property is called. I'm bit puzzled about what to do. I'd like this code to update value of Setting's value field and then persist it in my DB.

I'm using JBoss 7.1.1.Final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following approach. First, in your bean, add the following:

```
private Map<String, Setting> settingsByCode = new HashMap<>();

@PostConstruct
public void initializeSettingsByCode() {
    for(Setting setting : settings) {
       settingsByCode.put(setting.getCode(), setting);
    }
}

public Map<String, Setting> getSettingsByCode() {
    return settingsByCode;
}
```

In your XHTML, change the EL expression to the following:

```
<p:inputMask value="#{settingsBean.settingsByCode['SSTMOUT'].value}" mask="9?99"/>
```

Comment: Work like a charm. :) Tank you.